# Calculating the positions of three touching circles based on their radius

Tags: geometry, raphael

This is ultimately a problem of geometry. I'm using raphaeljs to draw 3  area circles for each item in a series of data. Each circle represents the number of items in a category.

I would like the circles to touch but not overlap, and I would like the whole set to center in the middle of its parent div.

Diagram here: http://chriscanipe.com/images/circles.jpg

Knowing only the radius of each circle and the width and height of the parent div, how would I go about calculating the xy coordinates be for the center of each circle? The more I think about it, I think I'm actually trying to draw a triangle where each corner is the x,y center of a circle.

Comment: Can you update the question with the image? The link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of constraints you will need to limit or chose here above and beyond your initial question. In your example image, how have you decided to rotate the triangle formed by the centres? What are you calling the "centre" of the triangle?

One way to approach this might be:

Assume the first circle at the origin (0,0)
Assume the second circle at a point directly above this (0,r1+r2)
Calculate the third point - this is the intersection of two circles. One is centred on the origin and has radius r1+r3 and the other is centred at (0,r1+r2) and has radius r2+r3.

Now you have these three points you can calculate a "centre"

Then you can draw your circles based on this centre and the dimensions of your div.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the [Circles of Apollonius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius) problem.  You can find solutions using the link.

I've worked on iterative generalizations of this. Given two curves A and B tangent to each other curves, transform a third curve C so that it is tangent to the other two.  The user provides some hints in the form of point selections on the two fixed curves.   The algorithm proceeds as follows:

1. Let p and q be the selected points projected onto A and B.
2. Transform C so that it is incident to p and q.
3. Since we don't expect C to be tangent to A and B at p and q, we need to find a new choice of p and q.
4. Compute osculating circles (or lines where the curvature is 0) at p and q for the curves that meet at those points.
5. Compute the chords of intersection between the circles (and lines).
6. Take p and q as the projections of the mid-points of the chords onto A and B, and repeat from 2, until the chords of intersection are small enough.

There are lots of niggly details of course, but anyone capable of implementing this algorithm should be able to work those out.

I'll add an illustration soon, but I don't have access to Mathematica at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation of my solution to this problem.
It incorporates a lot of geometry and trig identities - but no calls to trig functions.

```
HTML >>>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Tangent Circles in a Box
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/tangent_circles.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main_container">
      <div id="inner_container">
        <img class="circle" id="left_circle" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Z/Z/S/Y/S/w/red-circle-cross-transparent-background-md.png" alt="left_circle" />
        <img class="circle" id="right_circle" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Z/Z/S/Y/S/w/red-circle-cross-transparent-background-md.png" alt="right_circle" />
        <img class="circle" id="third_circle" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Z/Z/S/Y/S/w/red-circle-cross-transparent-background-md.png" alt="third_circle" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="userControls">
      <form id="userControlsForm">
        Circle One <input id="circleOneInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter Numeric Value" value=""><br>
        Circle Two <input id="circleTwoInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter Numeric Value" value=""><br>
        Circle Three <input id="circleThreeInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter Numeric Value" value="">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/tangent_circles.js"></script> 
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
HTML <<<

CSS >>>
body 
{
  background-color: white;
}

#main_container
{
  background-color: #cccccc;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid #cccccc 1px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}   

  #inner_container 
  {     
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }   

    .circle
    {
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: fantasy;
    }
        #left_circle
    {
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
    }

    #right_circle
    {
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
    }

    #third_circle
    {
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
    }

    #userControls
    {
      padding: 30px;
      width: 400px;
      height: 200px;
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 30px;
      background-color: #dddddd;
    }

      #circleOneInput
      {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      #circleTwoInput
      {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

#userControls
{
  position: absolute;
  left    : 20px;
  top     : 50px;
  width   : 200px;
}
CSS <<<
 JS >>>
$(function() {
  function changeCircles(){
    $("#inputWarning").remove();
    var radius1 = parseInt( $("#circleOneInput").val(), 10);
    var radius2 = parseInt( $("#circleTwoInput").val(), 10);
    var radius3 = parseInt( $("#circleThreeInput").val(), 10);
    console.log( 'radius1 = ' + radius1 + ', ' +
                 'radius2 = ' + radius2 + ', ' +
                 'radius3 = ' + radius3
      );
    if ( isNaN( radius1 ) || isNaN( radius2 ) || isNaN( radius3 ))
    {
      $("#userControlsForm").after('<span id="inputWarning" style="color: red;">Only Numbers Please</span>');
    }
    else
    { 
      // normalize circle sizes

      if (radius1 < 10)
      {
        radius1 = 10;
      }

      if (radius2 < 10)
      {
        radius2 = 10;
      }

      if (radius3 < 10) 
      {
        radius3 = 10;
      }

      if (radius1 > 150)
      {
        radius1 = 150;
      }

      if (radius2 > 150)
      {
        radius2 = 150;
      }

      if (radius3 > 150)
      {   
        radius3 = 150;
      } 

      // do the actual circle changing
      // 1) calculate
      // 2) animate
      // calculate sides of triangle
      var a = radius2 + radius3;
      var b = radius1 + radius3;
      var c = radius2 + radius1;

      // get dimensions of containing div
      var container_width  = $("#inner_container").width();
      var container_height = $("#inner_container").height();

      var center_x = container_width / 2.0;
      var center_y = container_height / 2.0;

      // calculate cosine and sine of angle inside circle b
      var cos_beta = ((a * a) + (c * c) - (b * b))/(2 * a * c);
      var sin_beta = Math.sqrt( 1 - cos_beta * cos_beta );

      // calculate coordinates of circles a and b
      var Ax = 0;
      var Ay = 0;
      var Bx = radius1 + radius2;
      var By = 0;

      // calculate cosine and sine of angle between triangle and horizontal
      var cos_phi = (Bx - Ax)/c;
      var sin_phi = Math.sqrt( 1 - cos_phi * cos_phi );

      // calculate the cosine and sine of the sum of both angles
      var cos_phiNbeta = cos_phi * cos_beta - sin_beta * sin_phi;
      var sin_phiNbeta = cos_phi * sin_beta + sin_phi * cos_beta;

      // calculate coordinates of circle c
      var Cx = Bx - cos_phiNbeta * a;
      var Cy = By + sin_phiNbeta * a;

      // find centroid
      var centroid_x = (Ax + Bx + Cx) / 3.0;
      var centroid_y = (Ay + By + Cy) / 3.0;

      // get coordinate adjustment
      var adjust_x = center_x - centroid_x;
      var adjust_y = center_y - centroid_y;

      // convert coordinates to div position values
      var A_left = Ax + adjust_x - radius1;
      var A_top  = Ay + adjust_y - radius1;
      var B_left = Bx + adjust_x - radius2;
      var B_top  = By + adjust_y - radius2;
      var C_left = Cx + adjust_x - radius3;
      var C_top  = Cy + adjust_y - radius3;

      // calculate div dimensions
      var A_width  = 2 * radius1;
      var A_height = 2 * radius1;
      var B_width  = 2 * radius2;
      var B_height = 2 * radius2;
      var C_width  = 2 * radius3;
      var C_height = 2 * radius3;

    // the following needs Jquery
      var circle_a = $("#left_circle");
      var circle_b = $("#right_circle");
      var circle_c = $("#third_circle");

      circle_a.animate( {
                        'top'   : A_top + 'px',
                        'left'  : A_left + 'px',
                        'width' : A_width + 'px',
                        'height': A_height + 'px'
                        }, 500 );

      circle_b.animate( {
                        'top'   : B_top + 'px',
                        'left'  : B_left + 'px',
                        'width' : B_width + 'px',
                        'height': B_height + 'px'
                        }, 500 );


      circle_c.animate( {
                        'top'   : C_top + 'px',
                        'left'  : C_left + 'px',
                        'width' : C_width + 'px',
                        'height': C_height + 'px'
                        }, 500 );


    }
  }
  $("#circleOneInput").keyup(changeCircles);
  $("#circleTwoInput").keyup(changeCircles);
  $("#circleThreeInput").keyup(changeCircles);
}); // end ready
 JS <<<
```